# Why Does Drupal 7 Keep My Terminated Session in the "sessions" Table?

Tags: mysql, session, drupal, drupal-7

I am creating a separate web application which uses the Drupal 7 "sessions" table to validate users. The problem I am having is when there is only one session remaining in the table. If I log out, Drupal will not delete that final session on its own; the session remains in the table thus allowing me to still login to my other system. Obviously this could pose a security risk in the future.

If I log in with my Drupal account again, Drupal simply creates a second session with the same uid. When I log out, Drupal deletes that session but the other session still remains. If it makes any difference, this is a local installation so my hostname is logged as ::1.

Comment: Have you tested whether  the old session really still has "logged in" status? I doubt that. That would be a severe bug. Keeping a session around but stripping it of all privileges sounds like something that may be by design, though.

Comment: Right I'm not "logged in" through Drupal anymore. But I can still access my other system because the session is still in the "sessions" table. I will dig deeper to see if, in fact, Durpal leaves one session there on purpose.

Comment: I don't know Drupal well, but I think you'll definitely need your web app to validate for Drupal's actual "logged in" state, not just the existence of a session. There may be existing solutions for that - "Drupal Single Sign On" being the keyword for a search